# Interval of distribution is underrepresented in sample: Is there a way to estimate frequency in ground truth?

Tags: distributions, terminology, truncated-normal-distribution

I heard about the concepts of censored and truncated data. Now I'm searching for the right concept to express something that is similar to truncated data:

As far as I understood, in truncated data there is a bound and all values outside this bound are entirely omitted. In my sample, values outside a specific bound are not entirely omitted but underrepresented due to a known reason.

Additionally to the first sample, there is a second sample, where the values outside the bound are not underrepresented.

My questions are:

1. is there a name/concept in statistics to describe that kind of situation?
2. is there a way to estimate the frequency of the underrepresented values from sample 1?

Comment: Can you tell us about the known mechanism?